# Doubt regarding Mathematical Olympiad preparation.

Tags: reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

My question is: Should we make notes in olympiad preparation and if so, then how?

I am in grade 10 in India and am preparing for JEE (entrance exam for IIT's including Physics, Chem and routine Math (not olympiad stuff). While i study those topics, i always make notes from various sources as revision is very important for those subjects, but I am not sure if I should make notes while preparing for Mathematical Olympiad, as there isn't really much need for revising theorems per se. So when reading the text, should i just read it , understand it and do problems or also make notes?

If any of you have prepared for olympiads, your valuable insights would be much appreciated. Thanks.

NOTE: This is a general question related to math and not a problem, i am not sure if we are allowed to post it here so if anyone feels any problem, do let me know, i'll delete this post.

Comment: I think it is better to ask this question on the site about math education. But in general having notes could be useful for some people. In case of olympiad you can keep note of interesting problems with new ideas if this help you learn better these ideas. Also doing this could be useful if you later want to teach these ideas

Comment: I think it just depends on whether or not you think it will help you to master the material. Some people find it helpful to write blog posts or books explaining what they've learned. (Terence Tao is a good example of this. He wrote a book about problem solving when he was like 15, and he's a prolific blogger / book writer.) Often when you understand something clearly for the first time you feel an urge to explain it.